# How to prove the convergence of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfies the inequality 
$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\right|\leq \sqrt{n}$ for all $n$. How to prove that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k}$$ is convergent?

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you have $|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k| < \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: @madprob Thank you for pointing out. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Apply Cauchy criterion.

Summing by parts with $S_k = \sum_{j=1}^k a_j$,

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{a_k}{k}\right| = \left|\frac{S_m}{m} - \frac{S_n}{n+1} +\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}\frac{S_k}{k(k+1)} \right| \\\leqslant \frac{|S_m|}{m} + \frac{|S_n|}{n+1} +\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}\frac{|S_k|}{k(k+1)} \\ \leqslant \ldots$$